# Missing a reason for bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I just created a bounty and I would required to select one of the following reasons:

- Authoritative reference needed
- Canonical answer required
- Current answer are outdated
- Draw attention
- Improve details
- Reward existing answer

How about "still looking for a correct answer"? Now, my thinking is probably biased by my current situation, but isn't that the main to ask a question in the first place?...because you are looking for an answer?  Why shouldn't this also be an option for a bounty?

Comment: Draw Attention tends to mean the same thing for me, if you are looking for an answer and have not received one then drawing attention to the question would be the same as looking for a correct answer.

Comment: I would agree with Michael that "Draw Attention" is your best option in this case. It is a given that by asking a question you are looking for an answer. The choices you are provided are more to explain why you are willing to offer a bounty, not why you are asking the question.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, "Draw attention" is indeed the correct option if you are still looking for an answer.